# Maximum 20 cookie per domain - Why?

Tags: asp.net, http, cookies

I've just come across an interesting fact, apparently a website can have up to 20 seperate cookies.

Ok - fair enough.

But why on earth would you store more than say "UserID", and why would you possibly need 20 cookies?

Comment: Maybe for subdomains? Good question..

Comment: Any URLs for that _20 cookies_ statement?

Comment: @Uwe - I read the statement http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/18128 after doing an ASP.NET quiz (where I got the cookie answer wrong!)

Comment: BTW, I think storing the UserID (int) would be a pretty bad idea, since it would be easy to hijack other accounts.

Comment: @Uwe - Well obviously that was just an example, it would be some kind of userID that the server can understand.  Once logged out the cookie can be made to expire

Comment: But why limitation to 20 cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you offer the user a way to customize your site you need to store their settings somewhere.
You might need cookies for:

- user settings
- the session id
- the contents of a shopping basket
- the last item viewed
- the user login

Comment: But is cookies the best way forward, surely you'd store any customisations server side

Comment: you could store them server side, it's up to you which method is better for you

Comment: If you have a user logging in from several different computers at different times, you need to store their settings per browser

Answer (score 1):

Some that I can think of:

- persistent login cookie
- session cookie
- user-independent settings
- user-tracking-cookie

Answer (score 0):

It's a choice. If you don't need 20 cookies, it doesn't mean somebody else won't.

Comment: I just don't understand the option why though?  Surely store a userID in the cookie and not much else?

Comment: @m.edmondson: @thejh and @PiedPiper have listed some nice uses for multiple cookies. If your site becomes very complex, it can be very useful to put information on client side. Especially if your site's look can be customized and you want your users to retain that even if they don't have to log on.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with PiedPiper and thejh. If you are storing user info and customizing the behaviour of your site based on users actions, then very soon you will run out of storage limit of single cookie.

Comment: So why not store customisations server side? Where you keep full control

Comment: Customisations will be on server side, for sure. But we need to keep some idenfiers on client machine so that we can tie it back to server records. More scenario is like when I have basket functionality in my site and I support multiple baskets at once.

Answer (score 0):

A site can have multiple pages, and a lot of those pages may have some information that might in turn be stored in cookies. It is ironic that you ask WHY you may want to use a lot of cookies where as I have seen a lot of people complaining why ONLY 20!!!

It is a good practice to ensure that you DO NOT create a lot of cookies, simply because IE has 20 cookie limit. Other browsers may have more [or less]!